# Is present continuous necessary to describe a current ongoing process?

Tags: present-tense, present-progressive

I realize that idiomatically the present continuous is used to describe a current ongoing process, but is the tense necessary? Could the present tense with a current adverb suffice?

Is it grammatical to say:

> I study English now.
>
> Or, I study English currently.

Do I need the present continuous?

Comment: Your first version implies a contrast with the past (when you *didn't* study English , whereas the second one implies contrast with the future (when you *will no longer* be studying English).

Comment: Plus, the second one sounds pretentious. In conversation, neither are common. `I'm studying English now.` is **far** more common, though it has a slightly different meaning. It really depends on the context. To be clear... what is the term in response to? A question? `Are you studying French at University?` or `What language are you studying now?`

Comment: The second one would be better " Currently I study English" but like the previous comment it needs the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a tense is necessary or not depends on the speaker's intention and the idiomatic background from which they cull their language.

The present tense can be modified with words such as **now**, **currently**, **at present**, **at the moment**, **lately**, etc.

As to whether present tense expressions that use these adverbials sound "artificial" "stilted" or "phony" is a matter of opinion.  Often, what sounds "correct" to a native speaker is just a matter of their idiomatic background--*even on "official" matters of grammar.*

The verb "like" isn't used in the present continuous (not by me, at least) so those adverbials are normally used.  *Now, I like vanilla ice cream*, is perfectly fine, as is, *Currently, she likes Sherlock Holmes stories.*  There are a number of stative verbs that aren't normally used with the present continuous, love or hate being others.

Answer (score -1):

" I sudy English now " sounds odd.

Shakespeare could say so when Ophelia asks : “What do you read, my lord?”,

not "What are you reading, my lord?"